# How to set environment varibles in gcloud command?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy an app engine Managed VM python/flask application using the `gcloud` command.

When developing locally I can pass environment variables to my flask server. I do this so that I can read a config file per environment. For example:

```
gunicorn -b :8080 --env CONFIG_FILE=config_dev.py main:app
```

Now, i'd like to deploy my application and use `config_production.py` as my config file. It seems I'd need to pass the environment variable `CONFIG_FILE=config_dev.py` to `gcloud preview app deploy` to set it. I checked the help pages but didnt see a way to set this.

Previously when I was developing on app engine sandbox I could do:

```
appcfg.py -E ENVIRONMENT:dev update app.yaml
```

Is there an equivalent argument for gcloud?

Comment: You can set environment variables directly in your `app.yaml` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables to be aceesed by `os.environ`

Comment: Another alternative. In your `app.yaml`'s entrypoint section, you could try `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 --env CONFIG_FILE=config_dev.py main:app`

Comment: I see. So you're suggesting creating different app.yaml files for each of my environments? so.. app_staging.yaml, app_prod.yaml

Comment: That's certainly one approach. That way you can treat `app_staging.yaml` & `app_prod.yaml` as modules https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#an_example

Comment: Curious to know what approach you took?

Comment: Im using a different yaml file for each environment. Seems redundant, but couldn't figure out a better way to get env variables into the runtime from the cli.

Comment: @sthomps is there a way to set the env variables runtime from the cli ?